# Write permission of a file in unix

Tags: linux, unix, file-permissions, chmod, umask

While assigning permissions to a file with the command:

```
$ chmod +rwx file1.txt
```

Why is it that read and execute permissions are assigned to everybody, but write permission is only assigned to the user?

Comment: Read up on `umask`

Answer (score 1):

yes it depends on the umask of your system u might be  having 0022 as your umask

```
chmord +rwx file.txt ---- 777
```

the resulting permission 777-022=755

Answer (score 0):

> **chmod(1)**
>    A combination of the letters `ugoa` controls which users' access to the file will be  changed:  the  user  who  owns it (`u`), other users in the file's group (`g`), other users not in the file's group (`o`), or all users (`a`).  **If**  none  of  these are  given,  the  effect  is as if (`a`) were given, *but bits that are set in the  `umask` are not affected.*

This is pretty clear. You have to check your umask value:

```
$ umask 
0002
$ touch xyz
$ ls -l xyz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 0 Sep  6 22:56 xyz
$ chmod +rwx xyz
$ ls -l xyz
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user 0 Sep  6 22:56 xyz
```

---

```
$ chmod a+rwx xyz
$ ls -l xyz
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user 0 Sep  6 22:56 xyz
```

Have a look at this page: [Default File Permissions: `umask`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/817-3814/userconcept-95347/index.html)

Comment: Thanks. But I wanted to know the reason why chmod +rwx doesn't assign write permissions to group and others.

Comment: @KavyaJain Have you read `chmod(1)`  `umask(2)` man pages? If so please do so.